# How do you make a program that detects if a a word in an array is a heterogram? That would output it as True and False?

Tags: python

```
def hetemoro(s):
    hash = [0] * 26
    x = 0
    repeat = 0
    register = 0
    result = []
    new_list = []
    while(repeat <= 2):
        activity = ''.join(c for c in s[x] if c.isalpha()) #Necessary in order to allow 's' to exclude all numbers
        new_list.append(activity.lower())
        repeat += 1
        x += 1
    x = 0
    repeat = 0
    while(repeat <= 2):
        ignore = 0
        a = new_list[x]
        n = len(a)-1
        for i in range(n):
                if hash[ord(a[i]) - ord('a')] == 0:
                    hash[ord(a[i]) - ord('a')] = 1
                else:
                    value = (s[x], False)
                    result.append(value)
                    register += 1 
                    if (register == 3):
                        print(result)
                    ignore = 1
                    x += 1  
                    repeat += 1
        if (ignore == 0):
            value = (s[x], True)
            result.append(value)
            register += 1
            if (register == 3):
                print(result)
            x += 1   
            repeat += 1
    return result
```

Am I missing something? Because the output is just

```
hetemero(['great', 'dgss', 'may'])
hetemero(['a25a', 'agd', 'ss25'])
[('great', True), ('dgss', False), ('may', False)]
[('a25a', True), ('agd', False), ('ss25', True)]
```

Which is wrong since 'may' is definitely true, I think the code has some mistakes in the process and I need some help in understanding what I need to add and remove so that it can move smoothly

Comment: Your code seems pretty complex for what it's doing - checking if the count of every letter is less than or equal to 1? just trivially, `all(v <= 1 for Counter(string.lower()).values())`?

Comment: "Here's my undocumented broken code, please debug it for me" is unlikely to attract much attention. [ask]

Comment: or `len(set(string)) == len(string)`...

Answer (score 0):

Is this the function You were going for:

```py
def func(words):
    return [(word, len(set(word)) == len(word)) for word in words]
```

The reason to use sets is because they can't contain duplicate values so if in word there is a letter that repeats it will be eliminated thus the length of the set will be shorter than the word

Comment: If you are going to 'add the glue' on  top of my answer in the comment you may as well make it a pythonic 1-liner...

Comment: @Julien what does 'add the glue' mean? also edited the code to add the one-liner

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you everyone for your contribution I have found the solution with the help of you all.
Namely the person who suggested to add

```
if len(set(word)) == len(word):
            lst.append((words[x], True))
        else:
            lst.append((words[x], False))
        repeat += 1
```

So yes, the output is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Set is ok but it won't bring you lazy evaluation since the whole word is scanned to detect duplicated letters.
I would rahter use a dictionnary to keep track of each letter parsed and imediately return `False` if the next letter encountered is already stored. I will go with this implementation:

```
def is_heterogram(word):
  d = {}
  for letter in word:
    if letter in d.keys():
      return False
    d[letter] = None
  return True

def hetemero(words):
  return [(word, is_heterogram(word)) for word in words]

print(hetemero(['great', 'dgss', 'may']))
print(hetemero(['a25a', 'agd', 'ss25']))
```

Comment: This works too, as it uses the same principles. But since a heterogram would allow a repetition of a number I added.
`activity = ''.join(c for c in words[x] if c.isalpha())` 
so that I can make an entirely new list excluding numbers.